# How to reduce noise? (FlipFlop circuit creates lot of noise)

Tags: led, filter, noise, flipflop

I have [this flipflop circuit](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/a2.datacaciques.com/16/11/10/ch5st2elfj6j0m6z/ccca35dcc28a0088.png) and an [sound detector circuit](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/raYAAOSwDNdVg3zH/s-l1600.jpg) (amplifier + microphone). When connected to individual battery (NiMh) they work nice. But when connected to the same battery, the sound detector goes crazy. It looks like the flipflop is creating a lot of electric noise that reaches the amplifier.

My questions are:
1. Why an analog flip flop LED circuit creases so much noise? I expected this from digital circuitry not from a simple flipflop.
2. What kind of filter should I install to suppress the noise?

Comment: The sound detector detects via microphone sound in the room. When the sound level is over a threshold, a blue LED lights up. This works, when the circuit has its own battery. But when I connect also the flipflop to the same battery, the blue LED starts to flicker randomly even though there is no sound in the room. The only conclusion is that the flipflop creases some electric noise.

Comment: add a LARGE VALUE electrolytic capacitor from LED anodes to transistor emitters (ground).

Comment: The microphone is "on board", next to amplifier. No wires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have made **is** digital circuitry- it switches. Using the same unregulated supply is injecting noise into your amplifier through the battery power.

Possibly the problem is in the electret microphone front end receiving power from the battery without regulation or enough filtering, but we have no way of knowing what circuit the detector uses let alone redesigning it to work better.

If my guess is correct, a simple RC filter on the electret load may work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcwcqP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So, I need to put the filter on the electret, not on the sources of the noise (the flipflowp)?

Comment: You can certainly try putting a cap across the battery and it may help. Try at least 1000uF, preferably a motherboard type low-Z type. It should at least reduce the higher frequency components.

Comment: sound detector schematics: https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/raYAAOSwDNdVg3zH/s-l1600.jpg    It already has a puny 47uF cap.

Comment: I do actually have some low-Z capacitors from a mainboard :) Thanks. Since it is the easiest, it is the first thing to try.,

Comment: Dont be too quick to accept answer until it works.

Comment: @ElectroMan Okay, so the electret circuit is as I expected and illustrated in the schematics, and no filtering whatsoever, as I expected.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75-Adding a mainboard 3300uF/6.3V solved the ORIGINAL problem. But after adding yet another circuit to the same battery (this time a digital CMOS) the noise is back. So, I guess, I also need the filter on the microphone.  But again, adding the capacitor solved my ORIGINAL problem (the one with the flip flop).

Answer (score 1):

Follow Spehro for cct improvements and read this for EMC practice.

EM interference is simply a crosstalk of R,L and C.

### L

The current is not too large but the size of wire loop area creates  inductance between pulsed voltage near 0V and the ground return wire.  So this loop must be eliminated with twisted pair throughout the entire path to the LEDs, Q's and battery.  The proximity of high impedance Mic input makes it also necessary to shield the mic with shielded twisted pairs and perhaps Ferrite sleeve to reduce the inductive coupling from pulsed current induced into high Z mic.  This is Inductive noise.

### C

Capacitive noise is the crosstalk of dV/dt between low and high impedance signals. Shielding works best or twisted ground around signals, with no shared ground current from any other source or load.

A neat tight twisted wire layout works well with a twisted wire that carries no ground current to absorb stray C noise. Coax with connection at one end only works better but that is for shielded twisted pair.

### R

Conductive noises are from shared ground currents or supply currents and although you have done a good job with decoupling caps besure your mic circuit does not share any ground current with the noise source.

Second is that the current drawn by the LEDs,Q's and battery may share wires used by the amplifier circuit. Avoid this and use direct power and ground wires ( or radial Star method from Cap decoupled voltage source.)

Answer (score 0):

Supposes the FF pulls 10mA for 10 nanoseconds. Suppose there is coupling into a "loop" of the analog circuit, that loop being 4cm by 1cm. Some voltage will be induced, assuming 1cm separation from FF to analog circuit.

Vinduce = MUo * MUr * Area/(2 * PI * Distance) * dI/dT

Vinduce = 2e-7 * Area/Distance * dI/dT

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 4cm * 1cm/1cm * 1mA/nS

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 0.04 * 10^+6 amp/sec

Vinduce = 8 e-9 * e+6 = 0.008 volts

Comment: Hi. What to I do with this number (8mV)? Where is this voltage induced? Into the microphone?